# Avoid writing on a slave MariaDB server

Tags: replication, mariadb

I have a replication in place with a Master server and a slave server.

From time to time I connect to the slave server mostly to get info or generate statistics on my user's usage.

But I'm afraid that at some point I will run a write command (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) to that slave, thinking I'm on the master server.

Is there a way I can tell MariaDB: "Don't accept the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE commands" in the slave server?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I have managed replicas, I always set this on the replica:

```
SET GLOBAL read_only=ON;
```

Of course the replication thread gets to ignore this. But it ensures that all user requests (even superuser requests) cannot make out-of-band changes.

A user with SUPER privilege can still write changes on the replica even if `read_only` is enabled. Don't grant SUPER privilege to users.

On MySQL, you can solve this with:

```
SET GLOBAL read_only=ON, super_read_only=ON
```

But a user with SUPER privilege could get around that because they can change the setting.

The larger problem is if you can't trust the users to whom you grant SUPER privilege.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be what I'm looking for. Does this command sustain after a logout ? a restart ?

Comment: SET GLOBAL only lasts until the next restart of MySQL Server. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-variable.html for details. Make sure you are reading the documentation for the version you are using (`SELECT VERSION();`).

Comment: Thank you for the link. When running your command, I get the following "unknown system variable 'super_read_only'". (version: 10.5.18-MariaDB)

Comment: Remove the reference to super_read_only, and in the future please be clear that you're using MariaDB, not MySQL. These are different products.

Comment: Oh ok. Does the absence of "super_read_only" at Maria will allow any super user to be able to write? or does the "read_only" parameter is enough for all users (super or not) at MariaDB ?

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/read-only-replicas/: _"When the variable read_only is set to 1, no updates are permitted except from users with the SUPER privilege"_